# How to iterate over items inside a recyclerview adapter get a result and pass it to a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

Below is my recyclerview adapter, whenever my recyclerview is populated I iterate through all views and calculate total incomes and expenses and get the balance in a variable called MainAccountBalance. how to pass this variable value to my Mainfragment so I can show it on a textview on top of the recyclerview? any time the recyclerview items changes, or the recyclerview populated/repopulated the variable should automatically passed and updated on the textview.

Am new to this, a Kotlin detailed code would really be appreciated. Thanks.

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter(options: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<DataModel>) : FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<DataModel,  RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>(options) {
  private var listener: OnItemClickListener? = null
   private  var MainAccountBalance: Double = 0.00




    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int, model: DataModel) {
        holder.noteTextView.setText(model.transaction_note)
        holder.transactionDateTextView.setText(model.transaction_timestamp?.let { convertLongToDateString(it) }).toString()

        var totalIncome: Double = 0.0
        var totalexpense: Double = 0.0

        // change the money to red or blue based on the transaction type
        val transaction_type = model.transaction_type
        if (transaction_type=="expense") {
            holder.amountTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D12E9A"));
            holder.amountTextView.text = model.transaction_amount?.let { replaceArabicNumbers(convertIntToCurrencyString(it)) }
            totalexpense =model.transaction_amount!! + totalexpense

        }
        else {
            holder.amountTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3A86FF"))
            holder.amountTextView.text = model.transaction_amount?.let { replaceArabicNumbers(convertIntToCurrencyString(it)) }
            totalIncome = model.transaction_amount!! + totalIncome
        }
```

```
    MainAccountBalance = totalIncome - totalexpense



}

public fun replaceArabicNumbers(original: kotlin.String): kotlin.String {
    return original
        .replace("٠","0")
        .replace("١","1")
        .replace("٢","2")
        .replace("٣","3")
        .replace("٤","4")
        .replace("٥","5")
        .replace("٦","6")
        .replace("٧","7")
        .replace("٨","8")
        .replace("٩","9")
        // arabic decimal point = U+066B
        .replace("٫",".")
        // thousands grouping seperator = U+066C
        .replace("٬",",")
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val v: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_main_account_item,
            parent, false)
    return MyViewHolder(v)
}

fun deleteItem(position: Int) {
    snapshots.getSnapshot(position).reference.delete()
}

inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var transactionDateTextView: TextView
    var noteTextView: TextView
    var amountTextView: TextView


    init {
        transactionDateTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.transactionDateTextView)
        noteTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.noteTextView)
        amountTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.amountTextView)//



        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val position = adapterPosition
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null) {
                listener!!.onItemClick(snapshots.getSnapshot(position), position)
            }
        }
    }
}

interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(documentSnapshot: DocumentSnapshot?, position: Int)
}

fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: OnItemClickListener?) {
    this.listener = listener
}



fun convertLongToDateString(systemTime: Long): kotlin.String {
    //return SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy' Time: 'HH:mm")
    return SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
            .format(systemTime).toString()
}

fun convertIntToCurrencyString(money :Double): kotlin.String {
    //currency formatter
    val formatter: NumberFormat = DecimalFormat("#,###.##")
    val myNumber = money
    val formattedNumber: kotlin.String = formatter.format(myNumber)

    return formattedNumber
    //currency formatter
}
```

}

Comment: @AlexMamo The code is fine, in the onBindViewHolder I have a variable "MainAccountBalance", its value comes from iterating through the views, and I want to pass its value to my fragment where the recyclerview lies. I do not now know how to do this, I read implementing an Interface is a solution to this, but most examples I found have OnClick on them, in my case I do not need the user to click to get "MainAccountBalance" value. Would really appreciate your help Alex, am new to this, be patient with me please. am using Kotlin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are using `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` data is updated automatically and you have no control on it, there are some options I explain one of them that can help you :

in your adapter class add a method like this :

```
 fun getAcountBalance():String{
   // iterate and update value of MainAccountBalance
   // add a log to check if your calculated value is correct
   return MainAccountBalance.toString() 
 }
```

in your activity or fragment where you are using this adapter do this (if you are using fragment do onCreate part in onViewCreated) :

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    .....
    
    // define yourTopTextView before this part

    // initialize your adapter
    val yourAdapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(...)
    //add observer to adapter changes 
    yourAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : 
    RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        // setText the view after any change
        
        override fun onChanged() {
            super.onChanged()
            setTextOfYourView(yourAdapter.getAcountBalance())
        }

        override fun onItemRangeChanged(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
            super.onItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount)
            setTextOfYourView(yourAdapter.getAcountBalance())
        }

        override fun onItemRangeChanged(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int, payload: Any?) {
            super.onItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount, payload)
            setTextOfYourView(yourAdapter.getAcountBalance())
        }

        override fun onItemRangeInserted(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
            super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount)
            setTextOfYourView(yourAdapter.getAcountBalance())
        }

        override fun onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
            super.onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart, itemCount)
            setTextOfYourView(yourAdapter.getAcountBalance())
        }

        override fun onItemRangeMoved(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int, itemCount: Int) {
            super.onItemRangeMoved(fromPosition, toPosition, itemCount)
            setTextOfYourView(yourAdapter.getAcountBalance())

        }
    })
    // set adapter to recycler view
    youRecyclerView.adapter= yourAdapter
}

fun  setTextOfYourView(balnce :String){
    yourTopTextView.setText(balnce)
}
```

Comment: Am sincerely grateful Amir, Thanks for your time, and for writing the code, much appreciated.